# What is the difference between Local timer interrupts and the timer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, cpu-architecture

When I do `cat /proc/interrupts` on my multicore x86_64 desktop PC (kernel 3.16) I see this:

```
0:         16          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
LOC:     529283     401319   Local timer interrupts
```

When I do `cat /proc/interrupts` on my multicore x86_64 laptop (kernel 3.19) I see this:

```
0:    1009220          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
LOC:     206713     646587   Local timer interrupts
```

When I saw this difference, I asked myself what the difference between those two is?

I hope someone can explain this rather thoroughly, the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931134/why-the-count-of-io-apic-edge-timer-showed-in-proc-interrupts-does-not-change-o) is not very detailed and does not explain why my desktop PC does not use timer, but my laptop does.

Comment: Given that from `0:` there are only 16 interrupts and all in CPU0, I'd dare say that they are the timer interrupts before the multi-cpu mode kicks in. Then each CPU will get its own local timer interrupt and the global one is disabled. Just guessing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the count of IO-APIC-edge timer showed in /proc/interrupts does not change often?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931134/why-the-count-of-io-apic-edge-timer-showed-in-proc-interrupts-does-not-change-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your apparently x86_PC architecture :

---

**IRQ 0** is the interrupt line associated to the first timer (Timer0) of the **P**rogrammable **I**nterval **Timer**. It is delivered by the [IO-APIC](https://docs.kernel.org/x86/i386/IO-APIC.html) to the boot cpu (cpu0) only.
This interrupt is also known as the *scheduling-clock interrupt* or
*scheduling-clock tick* or simply *tick*:

If the [NO_HZ](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) kernel configuration knob is not set (or under linux kernel versions < 3.10) This interrupt would be programmed to fire periodically at a [HZ](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HZ.html) frequency.
If NO_HZ is set then the PIT will work in its one-shot mode

Used at early boot times, it can still serve as the scheduling clock tick and for updating system time unless some *better* (*1) [clocksource](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timekeeping.txt) is found available.
It will anyway serve for cpu time accounting if [TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING.html) is set as part of the kernel configuration.

---

**LOC** are the interrupts associated with the [local APIC timer](https://wiki.osdev.org/APIC_timer).
which should be enabled to fire after some tedious initialization. (see hereabove link)

Then, depending on the cpu hardware capabilities to keep this clocksource stable in iddle times and [depending on kernel's configuration and boot command line parameters](https://github.com/linuxkit/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c) it will replace the PIC interrupt for triggering miscellaneous scheduler's operations, precise cpu time accounting and system time keeping.